# Does Refresher Shard work on Refresher Orb?

Tags: dota-2

In patch 7.07, Refresher Shard was added to the game. It is dropped by Roshan after his third death. How does it interact with Refresher Orb?

Is possible to use 4 ulties? Ulti - Orb - Ulti - Shard - Ulti - Orb - Ulti, provided you have enough mana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresher Shard is dropped after the 3rd Roshan death and **afterwards.**

It is possible to save several Refresher Shards, but each will use one slot inventory and have 200 s cooldown, independent to 195 s cooldown of Refresher Orb.

Refresher Shard will refresh any item in a hero's inventory, excluding those in Backpack, Refresher Orb, and other Refresher Shard(s).

Because there is **200 s *unrefreshable* cooldown**, you can only use one Shard in each fight. Combined with Refresher Orb, you can use **up to 3 sets** of spells and items in a fight.

Answer (score 2):

Refresher Shard does not refresh the cooldown of Refresher Orb or other Refresher Shards. You will only be able to use one of each in a fight.

Comment: "or other refresher shards".  You mean there is a possibility of having two refresher shards? AFAIK, there is only one possible per game

Comment: @MandeepJain Each Roshan after the second will drop a Refresher Shard

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Didn't knew that. Thanks :)

Comment: @SHRLY I stand corrected. That is possible. "The Refresher Shard does not share a cooldown with Refresher Orb. Combined with the lack of a mana cost, this means it makes it possible for heroes who already have a Refresher Orb to drop their spells three times in a fight." https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Refresher_Shard